# Chromium won't load any pages including settings page

Tags: chromium, browser, adblock

Chromium wouldn't load any pages including my settings page.  I noticed at the bottom left the status was saying something about loading "ad-block plus".

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to open the chromium menu and select "View Background Pages(n)", and that opened a system box that allowed me to end my ad-block plus process.  After doing this I was able to navigate to: `chrome://extensions/` and remove my extensions (ad-block and others I no longer wanted) to get the browser to function properly.  Hope this is some help to others having a similar problem!

Comment: Nice solution, given it solved it for you please mark it as the answer using the tick. What probably happened was that you installed the popular blocker ad-block plus, but something got messed up in it's blocklist so it blocked anything. (Probably some wildcard ended up in a config file or something).

Comment: Will do thanks, looks like it will only allow me to do that after 2 days however.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot it stopped you accepting your own answer for ages.

Comment: I try to open up the task manager but it crash chromium instead. but reopen chromium again it seems work fine because finally I could open the setting page to reset the browser. Anyway this answer works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just issue the following commands at the terminal to reset all Chrome settings:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome
```

It's working fine for me after doing this.